# Using Drivers to Limit Distance & follow Empty

Tags: drivers

I have a voxel "hair" object I am making, made of 110 separate Cubes.

Currently I am stuck with 2 challenges in making the Driver setup:

1. I want all of the cubes (Hairball objects) to be "Slow Parented" to an Empty (EmptyHead), so they delay following behind it.
2. There are several objects on the same Armature that the cubes are not supposed to touch.

Starting with the X location channel, and similarly for Y and Z, I will have the following variables:

self.location.x (from Use Self, for Hairball objects), EmptyX, HeadX, REyeX, LEyeX, ScutesX, WebX (Variables use Single Property of location.x based on the object they are referencing).

My ultimate goal is to have the objects with self.location.x to follow EmptyX with a slight delay, and to Limit Distance so that they never touch HeadX, REyeX, LEyeX, ScutesX, or WebX.

I have been racking my brain, and studying every answer I could find, but so far, to no avail.
I feel like there must be some way to do this with drivers - Though, I am unsure of how to proceed.
It may not be of much help, but I have attached a screenshot of the current project, simply for an idea of what I am working with.

Once I get the Driver set up properly, I will be joining the cubes into one object then separating by loose parts - To save me the headache of trying to write a script to apply the drivers to all objects.
I am awful with Scripts, so if it is possible to stick to a purely driver based solution I would be very happy, though I am more than willing to accept any help.

I am grateful for any possible assistance; Please let me know if I can provide any further information to aid in clarification / a solution.

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTdRGZA4TXA

Comment: I appreciate the help, though the video in question does not touch on, nor offer any form of insight to, any of the issues I am experiencing.

Comment: True, but my thought was you could parent the cubes to bones and side-step the driver issue entirely

Comment: Ahh, a good thought! I have tried that, and it does work somewhat - It doesn't work for the anti-collision effect. That being said, parenting the cubes to the main Control bone and adding Limit Distance Constraints did give a spectacular spherical effect of the cubes circling the armature - But they only seemed to be able to circle the origin point of the rig, not wherever it had moved to - Hence, my assumed need for drivers :)